# How can I keep a div fixed to the bottom of the window without having it overflow?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to pin a footer div to the bottom of a page div and have the footer always stay at the bottom of the screen.

Setting the style for the footer to "position:fixed; bottom:0;" as shown:

`#idFoot {background-color: silver; height:20px; width:100%; position:fixed; bottom:0;}`

does a nice job of setting the footer to the bottom of the screen but the footer's right edge is out of the viewport as you can see here:

[image: why the overhang?]

Why is it overflowing like this? How can I get it to line up with the edge of the containing  page div?

Is this the best way to get a div inside another div to span the outer div's entire width and get it to stick to the bottom of the screen?

I've attached all my code using stackexchange's code snippet feature but it renders my page in a very different manner than Chrome.

You can, however, still see that the footer fixed to the bottom is overflowing:

[image: still overflow]

```css
* {outline: 1px solid blue;}
html                        {background-color:lightblue;} 
body                        {background-color:lightgreen; overflow:hidden} 
                            
div, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5  {FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana; font-size:10pt}
                            
                            
#idPage                     {background-color:lightyellow; height:100%; overflow:auto; }
                            
#idFoot                     {background-color: silver; height:20px; width:100%; position:fixed; bottom:0;}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Attempt 7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">      
</head>


<html>
  <body> 
    <div id="idPage">
      <div id="idFoot">
      <div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `left: 0` and `box-sizing: border-box` on your fixed element ? you could also change width to `100vw` instead

Comment: It's overflowing because you've got an 8px margin on the body element. Setting the width to 100% sets the div width to 100% of the screen width but with the margin on, it overflows. Set body { margin:0 } or alternatively set both left and right properties.

Comment: @Caliph I rearranged my divs and and the overflow went away before I had a chance to try your suggestion but now the footer div is off the screen, that is you have to scroll to it.

Comment: @Adam, I do not see the 8px margin set in the body margin of which you speak?

Comment: @Adam I am reading your answer below and the margin that you are talking about is ..."Most body margins defaults are 8px". Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. Most body margins defaults are 8px so we'll set a css variable to that, set the body margin to that value then use that to the margin in the footer rule.

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

html {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  --margin: 8px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin: var(--margin);
}

div,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#idPage {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

#idFoot {
  background-color: silver;
  height: 20px;
  left: var(--margin);
  right: var(--margin);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="idPage">
  <div id="idFoot">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using position: absolute, it's better to stretch the footer div using right:0; left:0.
also give to the parent position: relative

```
  #idPage {background-color:lightyellow; position: relative; }
                        
  #idFoot {background-color: silver; height:20px; position:fixed; bottom:0; 
           left: 0; right: 0;}
```

Comment: you're missing a closing tag in html as well